# UICollectionView Multiple Cells Selection Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView in my iOS app and I am using Swift. I want to make UI like below:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I this UI when "Select" button is not selected (in first image) Tab bar is visible, but when "Select" button is selected (in second image), a new bar is visible. This is used for multiple cells selection. I just want to know, Is this functionality available by Apple (built in) or I have to make it manually (by myself)? (I have searched, but could not find)

Comment: My question is not about my code. I am just asking that, Is this functionality built in by Apple in UICollectionView or I have to make it.

Comment: **Multiple Cell Selection** in `CollectionView` is available in `iOS`. You can go through a good tutorial to build that.

Answer (score 0):

Collection View gives functionality to select multiple cells. Just write this code and you will be able to select multiple cells.

```
 yourCollectionViewName.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```